# How can I change the text color for ion-select items in Ionic 4?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I styled my alerts in `theme/variables.scss` like so (black background with white text)

```css
ion-alert {
    --background: black !important;
    --color: white !important;

    button {
        color: white !important;
        font-size: 20px !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Quantity</ion-label>
    <ion-select formControlName="quantity" placeholder="Select One">
        <ion-select-option value="1">1</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="2">2</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Now the problem is, when I add a select menu using `ion-select` the radio/select text (`ion-select-option`) is black, so it blends in with the background of the popup. I've tried about 30 different CSS classes and none of them are having any impact.

How do I change the color of the radio text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. The `.sc-ion-alert-md` class will change the text color of the radio labels. Tested in Chrome with both iOS and Android using `ionic serve`.

```
ion-alert.select-alert {
    --background: black!important;

    button {
        color: white !important;
        font-size: 20px !important;
    }

    .sc-ion-alert-md {
        color: white;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`<ion-select>` under the hood uses `<ion-alert>` which is why your style conflicts. You can use the `:not()` css to exclude the `<ion-select>`

```
ion-alert:not(.select-alert) {
  --background: black !important;
  --color: white !important;

  button {
    color: white !important;
    font-size: 20px !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Lifesaver! How would I go about styling the select alert? using `ion-alert:is(.select-alert)`? The documentation is ridiculous on this stuff, can't find anything anywhere!

Comment: Thanks. That lets me target the alert but I still can't figure out how to change the text color of the radio text, which is my original question. I've tried `color: white !important` and `--ion-text-color: white !important` and `--color: white !important` and none work.

Comment: While you didn't directly answer my question, you did give me something very useful in `:not(.select-alert)`; upvoted. Thanks!